# Make object variables be accesible within all "deeper" scope

Tags: javascript, object, this, private-functions

I'm currently coding a kind of plugin in JS. I've just learnt about objects, and I'm kind of annoyed by the fact that I can't access variables set within the constructor, two or more levels up. Here's what I mean:

```
    var myConstructor = function()
    {
        this.one = "one";
        this.two = "two";

        this.publicMethod = function()
        {
          console.log("I can access: ", this.one);
          var privateMethod = function()
          {
              console.log("I cannot access var two like this: ", this.two);
          };
          privateMethod();
        };
    };

var myObject =  new myConstructor();
myObject.one = 1;
myObject.two = 2;
myObject.publicMethod();
```

So, how could I make `privateMethod` access the variables that are set within the constructor? In the same manner that publicMethod uses `this` to do so. Is this possible? Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a duplicate of so, so many questions. Try searching next time.

Comment: Those are not *variables*, but *properties*  of the instance. Read about [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 var myConstructor = function()
        {
            this.one = "one";
            this.two = "two";

            this.publicMethod = function()
            {
                // new variable
                _two = this.two;
                console.log("I can access: ", this.one);
                var privateMethod = function()
                {
                    console.log("I cannot access var two like this: ", _two);
                };
                privateMethod();
            };
         };
```